# java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfileSetting) must not be null

Tags: kotlin

class  ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var binding : FragmentProfileBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

    return binding.root

}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.imgProfileSetting.setOnClickListener {

        Toast.makeText(context,"t",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
```

logcat ::   java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfileSetting) must not be null
}
}

Comment: you have shared wrong fragment code. Please share ProfileSetting Fragment

Comment: profile settings already

Comment: where is this code written ? ```logcat :: java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfileSetting) must not be null } }```